# Is there a word that means both "is compliant" and "is aware"?

Tags: single-word-requests

For example, a person that knows a rule exists and is following that rule.

(sorry if I'm doing this wrong- first post in this StackExchange)

Comment: I think to be compliant you first have to be aware that there is a rule. (Compliant = inclined to agree with others or obey rules) Therefore, *compliant* just may be the word you're looking for.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the expression **to abide by the rule**  implies the fact that you are both aware of a rule and that you conform to it.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good example of what you're after that I found online:

"He **observes the convention** without which scholarship would be impossible, namely that of not imposing one's own religious beliefs on the matter to be studied".

Answer (score 1):

He [**goes by the book**](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/do+by+the+book) or **does things by the book**.

> **go by the book**: to do something exactly as the rules tell you

Alternately, consider "**rule sticker**" and "**rule abider**."

> **rule sticker**: someone that sticks to the rules
>
> **rule abider**: someone that abides by the rules

Answer (score 0):

**Amenable**: [ready or willing to answer, act, agree, or yield; open to influence, persuasion, or advice; agreeable; submissive; tractable: an amenable servant.
2.
liable to be called to account; answerable; legally responsible: You are amenable for this debt.
3. capable of or agreeable to being tested, tried, analyzed, etc.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/amenable)

&

**Morigerant**:

> (Morigerate): Complying, obedient. a 1533 Ld. Berners Gold. Bk. M.
>   Aurel. (1546) Z viij b, The armies..were as well disciplined and
>   morigerate, as the schooles of the philosophies. Rolland Crt. Venus
>   iii. 14 Baith ald and ȝoung richt weill Morigerat. J. H. Newman Lett.
>   (1891) II. 199 They were morigerate, through the Exhortation and half
>   the Confession, when they bolted.][2] -http://useful_english.enacademic.com/246793/morigerate

Answer (score 0):

**Bureaucrat** emphasizes the knowing of the rule.

**Automaton** emphasizes following the rule.

Bureaucratomaton if you think we need more [portmanteaus](http://xkcd.com/739/).

Great and timely question, the next generation will have a word for this.